# orientation change jquery help needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, orientation-changes

Basing myself on the code at this URL : http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

I tried changing it so it could display a different image per orientation. That works fine using `$("#someID").html(< img src.../ >);`
but for some reason I can't get it to work as well using .addClass

Could someone please tell me why the following doesn't seem yield anything but a blank screen?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>orientationchange demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .landscape {
        background-image:url('images/landscape.jpg');
    }
    .portrait {
        background-image:url('images/portrait.jpg');
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="orientation" class="landscape"></div>
<script>
// Bind an event to window.orientationchange that, when the device is turned,
// gets the orientation and displays it to on screen.
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    if (event.orientation=="landscape") {
        //$("#orientation").removeClass("portrait");
        $("#orientation").addClass("landscape");
        return false;
    } else if (event.orientation=="portrait") {
        //$("#orientation").removeClass("landscape");
        $("#orientation").addClass("portrait");
        return false;
    }
});
// You can also manually force this event to fire.
$( window ).orientationchange();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, I got it to work now with dimensions definitions and combining addClass(class).removeClass(otherclass) but could someone please show me how I apply this same change to the body instead of the a div?

Comment: Did you try changing to orientation of the device, aka, shake it? Also, you may want to give a width and height to div#orientation.

Comment: Working normally, maybe as @watson has mentioned, give the dive height and width http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/d6jY6/show/ also remove classes not just adding.

Comment: @watson+@omar thanks for the replies, I'll give it a try right away =)

Comment: @Omar I get it to work fine using defined dimensions on the Div =) But I have an additional question, how can this be done using the "body" instead of the div? Substituting them doesn't work as well

Comment: could someone help me make it work with "body" instead of a div element? thanks )

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS you must include heights and widths. You can do this with JS but you actually need to specify height and width when you're using a background. Otherwise the div doesn't know how much space to take up. The background is, as the name implies, in the background.

```
 .landscape {
        background-image:url('http://duggal.com/connect/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Landscape-Nature-for-Wallpaper-Dekstop-.jpg');
    background-color: blue;
        width: 1020px;
        height: 900px;
    }
    .portrait {
        background-image:url('http://blogs.smithsonianmag.com/aroundthemall/files/2009/01/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg');
    background-color: black;
        width: 725px;
        height: 590px;
    }
```

Also, if you want to do without the two lines, you still need to get rid of the old class. You can do it with className, like so:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    if (event.orientation=="landscape") {
        //$("#orientation").removeClass("portrait");
        //$("#orientation").addClass("landscape");
        $("#orientation").get(0).className = "landscape");
        return false;
    } else if (event.orientation=="portrait") {
        //$("#orientation").removeClass("landscape");
        //$("#orientation").addClass("portrait");
        $("#orientation").get(0).className = "portrait";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's [My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maEZb/). It is done without .orientationchange() but the concept works nonetheless.

Comment: thanks a lot for the full reply, i'll try it right now! =) I've been trying to figure things out for a couple days now. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: the fiddle works fine, and I understand the code, but it doesn't seem to work in the orientationchange context :s the addClass.removeClass from a previous comment worked, with dimension definitions ofc.